# is my answer about probability correct?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Probability that a shooter with a shot to hit the mark is 0,78 what is probability if from 5 shots the shooter hit the mark 3 times. My answer is this: Let B be the event that the mark is hit 3 times. Then :
P(B)=(0,78)*(0,78)*(0,78)*(1-0,78)*(1-0,78). I'm supposing that three first times is hitting the mark, and the two lasts not. Is this answer correct and it would be same idea if it asks prob.to hit the mark 5 times P(B)=(0,78)^5

Comment: Why do you think the mark should specifically be hit in the first three trials, why can't it be any combo of three ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not correct.

The 3 hits can be in any position in the 5 shots and not necessarily in the first 3 positions as you stated. Thus you have to multiply your probability by $\binom{5}{3}=10$ say all the possible combinations of the 3 hits in the 5 shots

Thus the correct answer is

$$P(X=3)=\binom{5}{3}\cdot 0.78^3 \cdot 0.22^2$$

---

$P(X=5)=0.78^5$ is right because this is the unique possible combination

Comment: which probability has to multiple please and thank you for the answer.

Comment: @mathstudenteb:  added details in the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help...